# I need to install Windows 7 from ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows

I got ubuntu 16.04 for my computer but without many of the drivers was useless so i went to ubuntu 14.04, now i have to move to windows 7 because of some studies that require windows, problem is if i try to install it with the USB linux blocks me, any can help me please?

Comment: No, Linux doesn't block you and you don't install an OS "from" another. You boot from the installation media (depends on BIOS/UEFI and nothing else) and follow the steps for the OS you're trying to install.

Comment: thing is even with the BIOS im not allowed, cant access the other OS installation, and last time spent 30m on grub recovery for that, which is why i had to swap to 14.04

Comment: Nonsense! If it doesn't boot from the installation media when told so then you have a problem with that media. How to create installation media for Windows is, obviously, outside of the scope of AskUbuntu.

Comment: so how can i install windows from ubuntu?

Comment: How is it blocking you? Post specific errors and issues. Your question is extremely vague. You cannot directly install Windows from Linux. Asking how to create Windows installation media is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

In order to install Windows 7, you need to download a copy from [Microsoft's website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7). You will also need to purchase a product key. After this you need to create an install image (on a USB drive, or a CD) this should be possible through Ubuntu's startup disk creator utility. If you reboot into your BIOS, you select the drive, and it should guide you through the installation process.

It may not be possible to create Windows installation media from Ubuntu 14.04, but I have been able to from 16.04. In order to do this, you may need to borrow a Windows PC or a Mac from a friend.

This process will undoubtedly take some troubleshooting and patience (not to mention money for a license key). My suggestion if you are simply trying to run some windows software is to avoid the hassle of setting up a dual-boot system entirely. I recommend that you use a virtual machine, which can be a temporary or permanent solution, and completely free. A good option is generally Virtualbox, (Available in Ubuntu Software Center) it is available across-platforms and is free software. It is also possible to download a free version of Windows 7 from [Microsoft](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) that will work well with Virtualbox, or other Virtual Machine Software.

Best of Luck!

Comment: You certainly cannot create Windows media with Ubuntu's startup disk creator. It's always recommended to do it in Windows, using Windows tools.